# gwt html5 database SELECT WHERE AND

Tags: sql, database, html, gwt

iam using http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/downloads/list?q=label:API-Database
for my project.
there are two textboxes and the user can type in two words.
before these two words will be saved in html database i am looking if these two words are already in the the database saved.
the problem is i dont know how should look like the correct syntax for the 
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word1=value1 AND word2=value2.

```
final String word1 = view.getWord1TextBox().getValue();
final String word2 = view.getWord2TextBox().getValue();
if(Database.isSupported()){
         Database db = Database.openDatabase("Words", "1.0", "Word App", 10000);
         db.transaction(new TransactionCallback() {
                public void onTransactionStart(SQLTransaction tx) {
                    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM words WHERE word1=(?) AND word2=(?)", new Object[]{word1, word2}, new StatementCallback<JavaScriptObject>() {
                        public void onSuccess(SQLTransaction transaction, SQLResultSet<JavaScriptObject> resultSet) {
                             System.out.println(" count of rows : "+ resultSet.getRowsAffected());
                        }

                        public boolean onFailure(SQLTransaction transaction,SQLError error) {


                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }

                public void onTransactionSuccess() {

                }

                public void onTransactionFailure(SQLError error) {
                    //setTextMessageLabel("Could not open database", label );
                }
            });
    }
```

the resultSet.getRowsAffected() is everytime = 0
how should look like the correkt query?
or is there another problem?
please help

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your insert worked?

Does "SELECT * FROM words" return anything?

I use http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/wiki/DataServiceUserGuide so my syntax is a little different but using the developer tools in chrome you can find the database and run sqlite command in it.

Doing that, this gives me an error

> SELECT * from lesson where desc = (summer)

while using quotes works

> SELECT * from lesson where desc = ("summer")
>   SELECT * from lesson where desc = "summer"

You may need to escape it in your code...

```
"SELECT * FROM words WHERE word1=(\"?\") AND word2=(\"?\")"
```